# how to sort an array from highest to lowest and allowing the user to enter in part of the array, not the full amount alotted?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to sort the array from highest to lowest while also keeping their names next to their scores. Also, how do I allow the user to enter in only part of the array instead of the full 10 spaces allotted?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace proj09LEA
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SIZE = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare and array of integers          
            string[] name = new string[SIZE];
            int[] score = new int[SIZE];

            Console.WriteLine("\nSaturday Coder's Bowling Team");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score for each person on the team.");
            Console.WriteLine("For example, Mary 143. Just hit Enter when you are done.\n");

            // fill an array with user input
            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score: ");
                string line = Console.ReadLine();

                name[i] = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
                score[i] = int.Parse(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------ Input Complete ------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the scores for this game:\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}'s score was {1}.", name[i], score[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            AverageScore(score);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue. . .");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void AverageScore(int[] score)
        {
            int sum = score.Sum();
            int average = sum / score.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("The average score for this game was {0:d}.", average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use while loop and terminate when the user enters a value that indicates the finish of providing input.

Comment: I don't see any code related to your question in your post.

Comment: You should read http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/ and change the way you store the data. Instead of two parallel collections create a class, and have one array of that class instances.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> playerScoreList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
playerScoreList.Add(name, score); // add user to dictionary
playerScoreList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value); // sort by score descending
```